# Call Shell Command from PHP without considering output

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write a cronjob which launches multiple processes that I want to run in parallel.

I'm using a foreach calling each command, but the command line waits for the output. I don't want it to put.

Was wondering if anyone ever used any library for this?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ampersand after the command:

```
$ php task.php &
```

It will run that instance of php in the background and continue.

Comment: Note this only works on unix based systems use "start /B" + command, to do it on a windows server.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the manual on `passthru`](http://php.net/function.passthru) you'll notice it tells you how to avoid this...

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

So you can rely on UNIX fds to redirect output to something like `/dev/null` for example if you don't care about the output or to some file if you do want to save the output and this will avoid PHP waiting on the command to finish.

`pssthru("somecommand > /some/path/to/file")`